# optparse-applicative with custom monad

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

I'm trying to use my own monad (instead of `IO`) with `customExecParser` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.15.1.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Extra.html#v:customExecParser.

So I've ended up with (significant function being `fff`):

```
data MoscConfig = MoscConfig {
    datadir :: FilePath
  , config :: FilePath
  , pendingPath :: FilePath
  , socket :: FilePath
  }

type Mosco = StateT MoscConfig IO

main :: IO ()
main = join . customExecParser (prefs showHelpOnError) $
  info (helper <*> parser)
  (  fullDesc
  )

fff :: (a1 -> StateT MoscConfig IO a2) -> a1 -> IO a2
fff f  = (flip evalStateT (MoscConfig "" "" "" "")) . f

xyzz :: Text -> Mosco ()
xyzz x = do
  liftIO $ print x
  liftIO $ print "testabcxyz"

xyzz' :: Text -> Text -> Mosco ()
xyzz' x x' = do
  liftIO $ print x
  liftIO $ print x'
  liftIO $ print "testabcxyz"

parser :: Parser (IO ())
parser = do
  fff xyzz <$> textOption ( long "zzz" )
  <|>
  ((fmap fff) xyzz')
    <$> textOption ( long "zzz" )
    <*> textOption ( long "zzz" )
```

However, the only disadvantage with the above approach is needing to `fmap` the required number of times (matching the function arguments in `xyzz` or `xyzz`). I do recall running into this type of problem before. Is there some way I can avoid this (and just have a single function needing to be called)?

Ideally I'd hope to have a monad transformer for this but unfortunately this seems to be implemented to `IO` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this boils down to the question: is there a function `fff` that can be applied to both of:

```
xyzz  :: a -> r
xyzz' :: a -> b -> r
```

so that:

```
fff xyzz  :: a -> r'
fff xyzz' :: a -> b -> r'
```

And the answer is "no", at least not without some type class trickery that isn't worth considering.

Instead, assuming your real version of `fff` doesn't actually do anything with `f` except compose with it, I guess I would consider writing:

```
fff :: Parser (Mosco a) -> Parser (IO a)
fff = fmap $ flip evalStateT (MoscConfig "" "" "" "")

parser :: Parser (IO ())
parser = fff (xyzz  <$> textOption ( long "zzz" ))
     <|> fff (xyzz' <$> textOption ( long "zzz" ) <*> textOption ( long "zzz" ))
```

This whole approach seems a little "off", though.  Do you *really* need a `MoscConfig` available while *parsing* options?  Unless you have a really complicated options parsing problem on your hands, it would be more usual to parse the options directly into an intermediate data structure and then run your `Mosco` actions against that data structure to modify a `MoscConfig` state and do `IO` and so on.

Comment: Thanks! I should have stated in my question that I do intend to use the parameters - but I think you've answered the question none the less - in that I was fmaping unnecessarily .

Answer (score 1):

In terms of what I wanted to achieve (being able to just pass parameters to function within the `Mosco` monad context -

```
moscparams ::
  Maybe Text
  -> Maybe Text
  -> Maybe Text
  -> Maybe Text
  -> Mosco a -> IO a
moscparams dd c pp sp x = do
  ddd <- crFile
  cd <- pure "not used"
  ppd <- crDirPending
  spd <- socketFile
  evalStateT x
    $ MoscConfig
      (maybe ddd cs dd)
      (maybe cd cs c)
      (maybe ppd cs pp)
      (maybe spd cs sp)

moscF' :: Text -> Text -> Mosco ()
moscF' x x' = do
  liftIO $ print x
  liftIO $ print x'
  liftIO $ print "testabcxyz"

moscparams' :: Parser (Mosco ()) -> Parser (IO ())
moscparams' x = moscparams
  <$> optional (textOption ( long "data-dir" ))
  <*> optional (textOption ( long "config-path" ))
  <*> optional (textOption ( long "pending-path" ))
  <*> optional (textOption ( long "socket-path" ))
  <*> x

parser :: Parser (IO ())
parser = do
  moscparams'
    (( moscF')
      <$> textOption ( long "example-param-1" )
      <*> textOption ( long "example-param-2" )
    )
```